# What is the simplest way to create a network graph from a triple store?

Tags: user-interface, networking, graph, graphics

I have a simple triple store.

It is structured as follows :

```
Entity, verb, object
```

e.g, it may be

```
John, Supports, Manchester United
Fred, plays golf, Mark
Mark, Supports, Manchester United
```

From this I'd like a graph which will display the following info (hopefully in a slightly nicer format though! :) ) :

[image: Network graph showing all nodes from earlier triple store.]

What is the best API to do this with, and how can I best approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What you have is a simple ontology. There are many libraries to display this kind of data, for example: http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can approach is by using google organizational hierarchy it is really easy to use and program, for more information you can go across this [Google Organizational Hierarchy](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#overview). when it comes to the supporting frameworks i strongly suggest you to take a look at D3 JS, which is very useful for building visualizations using the data. Have a look over D3 Js [Here](https://d3js.org/). i hope these two references can help.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of graph theory work inside JavaScript. Instead of picking an API, I'd focus on the language you feel comfortable using, and then focus on the tools for that language.

The D3 graph libraries are a bit different than what you'd expect from something like an adjacency list (like I studied graphs in school.) I wrote [this collection of JavaScript programs](https://github.com/brian-stinar/d3-graph-theory) to help get things into a format D3 likes.

This also depends on the properties of your verbs. If a => b && b => a for all a and b ([symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation)) then you don't probably want directed graphs. If Fred plays golf with Mark, does Mark play golf with Fred? For all verbs?

Are your relationships [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)? If NOT, then it might make sense to create a new node for every time it's in a relationship, since visualizing them in the way you did makes me think John supports Mark who plays golf with Fred.

There are a bunch more [discrete math relationships](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Discrete_Mathematics/Functions_and_relations) you might want to consider.

I've also done a lot of graph theory inside Python. When I get a new graph theory problem, I like to use D3 for JavaScript, since I'm pretty good with JavaScript and already have some tools for it. If I need it to be super hardcore, I look into Python since it can run overnight on a server someplace.